# FitVid not working for iframes only on particular WP theme install

Tags: wordpress, iframe, responsive-design, themes

I am using FitVid in my theme and all is well except for a specific site that was migrated from Drupal. FitVid works fine with objects and embeds but not iframes, and only on this particular site. The only difference I can find is that a random `<noscript>` is inserted after the iframe.

Here is an example of the non working iframe on the problematic site:
http://wp.alimomeni.net/project/animal-warmth-no-64/

And here is an example with a different database where no  shows up:
http://wpfolio.notlaura.com/project/pollen-from-hazelnut/

Why is FitVid not working for iframes that particular site install? I am concerned there is an issue with the database itself as the content was pretty messy after the initial migration and I haven't been able to replicate the issue anywhere else.

Any help greatly appreciated!

P.S. I have tried other responsive video plugins and my own jQuery to wrap the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

Since the first "problem"'s being resolved, here's another try:

I saw that your fitVid-JS is different from mine. Maybe on purpose, but maybe it's outdated somehow. Here's what I am using in my script which works - for me:

```
    (function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(options){var settings={customSelector:null};if(!document.getElementById("fit-vids-style")){var div=document.createElement("div"),ref=document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0]||document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],cssStyles="&shy;<style>.fluid-width-video-wrapper{width:100%;position:relative;padding:0;}.fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe,.fluid-width-video-wrapper object,.fluid-width-video-wrapper embed {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}</style>";
    div.className="fit-vids-style";div.id="fit-vids-style";div.style.display="none";div.innerHTML=cssStyles;ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div,ref)}if(options)$.extend(settings,options);return this.each(function(){var selectors=["iframe[src*='player.vimeo.com']","iframe[src*='youtube.com']","iframe[src*='youtube-nocookie.com']","iframe[src*='kickstarter.com'][src*='video.html']","object","embed"];if(settings.customSelector)selectors.push(settings.customSelector);var $allVideos=$(this).find(selectors.join(","));
    $allVideos=$allVideos.not("object object");$allVideos.each(function(){var $this=$(this);if(this.tagName.toLowerCase()==="embed"&&$this.parent("object").length||$this.parent(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").length)return;var height=this.tagName.toLowerCase()==="object"||$this.attr("height")&&!isNaN(parseInt($this.attr("height"),10))?parseInt($this.attr("height"),10):$this.height(),width=!isNaN(parseInt($this.attr("width"),10))?parseInt($this.attr("width"),10):$this.width(),aspectRatio=height/width;if(!$this.attr("id")){var videoID=
    "fitvid"+Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);$this.attr("id",videoID)}$this.wrap('<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper"></div>').parent(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").css("padding-top",aspectRatio*100+"%");$this.removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width").css({'width': '', 'height': ''})})})}})(window.jQuery||window.Zepto);
```

Sry for minified code, I only copy & pasted it.

Comment: Ah, I had reverted to a previous commit yesterday when debugging. It's back in there now. Do you mean replace that line? Didn't seem to work for me

Comment: hmm. i'm sorry, but that beats me.
interesting: the video afterwards is processed correctly.
i'd try removing the `<noscript`-part after the first vimeo video. maybe that helps.

Comment: Well the <noscript> is added automatically somehow - it's very bizarre. Could it be a database corruption issue? The site was pretty messy when I initially transferred everything from Drupal.

Comment: ok, found a workaround: wrap your video in a `<figure class="media-wrap">`-tag. i looked at the other posts and found out that all other videos are using this. this should help, but doesn't solve the problem in the first place.

Comment: no, i doubt that it is a database issue. embedded videos are processed correct, an if i take you other site into account, you fitvid player also processes youtube videos correct. it seems to be an issue with vimeo videos.

Comment: Yeah, the .media-wrap was my original solution - there is a jQuery line that should wrap that around all iframes. I don't want to require users to go into the HTML though as I'm planning to release the theme. It seems like that line isn't triggering. The other posts had the tag added manually

Comment: did you try the different code that i pasted into my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - no difference unfortunately. This is really stumping me!